# Change location of a borderless form (C#)

Tags: c#, forms

How is it possible to move a borderless (FormBorderStyle.None) form out of window (= negative coordinates)?

I already tried the following things:

- this.Location = new Point(-10, -10);
- MoveWindow() from user32.dll
- SetWindowPos() from user32.dll

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you hide that window? this.Visible = false; may helps?

Comment: I already reserved some space on the top of the screen (with SHAppBarMessage). Now I try to move my window to this position.

Comment: the question remains why are you hiding a window by placing it off screen? It will still be eligible for input focus for example. It's the wrong way to do it. If you want to hide a window then just hide it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is; ( which not works under multi monitors)

```
this.Location = new Point(-1 * this.Width, -1 * this.Height);
```

You may hide your window by setting;

```
this.Visible = false;
```

Comment: and what about multi monitor systems?

Comment: if he targets multi monitor systems he should not play with the Location property to do this. he may set Visible parameter to false as Zuuum proposed above

Comment: target multi monitor systems? That's quite funny!

Comment: He asks how he can move that form out of window. So, what part of this question includes multi monitor systems?

Answer (score 1):

Once you created a task bar out of your window with SHAppBarMessage, the window's location is controlled by the shell, depending on what edge you selected.  You need to use either ABM_REMOVE, which destroys the task bar completely, or ABM_SETSTATE which lets you change it to an auto-hide task bar.  Moving another window on top of the task bar doesn't work, the shell prevents it to allow a task bar to behave like, well, a task bar.

Comment: i'm curious. Are there any real apps that create their own app bars? And if so why?

Comment: @David - some blasted Dell shovelware app preinstalled on one of my machines.  Yes, these programs don't stay installed for very long.  They usually target the browser anyway.

Comment: So that would be a "no" then if you factor in the "real app" condition?! I've seen that app bar stuff before but have never got my head round why it would be there and why anyone would be minded to use it.

Comment: @David - well, don't underestimate the niche apps, the kind we never see in the wild.  Lob, medical, retailing, etc.  The Windows task bar is pretty useful, there *has* to be somebody out there that found a similar use for his own stuff.  Presumably.  It's quite easy to get going in, say, Winforms.